# String Array in split with delimiter and value

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement to split request param in string array.

Suppose I am getting request in such way

```
<API_PATH>?reqPramName=gender=m*AND*age<30*OR*age>60*AND*address=India
```

Now I want to create two set of arrays 
1) query name/value array 
2) and/or conjunction array

Like

```
Array name/value 
------------------
0  | gender=MAN
------------------
1  | age<30
------------------
2  | age>60
------------------
3  | address=India

Array and/or
------------------
0  | AND
-----------------
1  | OR
----------------
2  | AND
```

I am doing the split operation such as ….

```
filter.split("AND|OR")
```

For the name/value  which is working properly, but can any one help me to construct the 2nd array(and/or array) from the request param?

My idea is to generate the Predicate depending on this two array by mapping this two array like …

```
1stArray[0]2ndArray[0]1stArray[1]2ndArray[1]
```

some thing like that...

Can any one suggest how I can generate 2nd array from the request param?

Comment: that is pseudo code only... by the way I am using java...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can any one suggest how I can generate 2nd array from the request param…

That one is actually pretty simple. You only need [String.indexOf(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))!

In other words: you can use that method to identify:

- where you have AND / OR substrings in your param string
- and you can do that *starting* from an index

Meaning: you could first do `indexOf("AND")` and `indexOf("OR")` to identify the **first** keyword. That gives an index i. Now you use the aforementioned method that takes an index, to search to the **right** of that first keyword.

In other words: this "only" requires you a bit of looping and searching within your param string.

But as mentioned in my comments: I think you are overlooking the real complexity of your idea. You are basically defining a *semantic* for the content of string. And you are introducing **operators**. If you are really serious about that, then you will have to consider [order of precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) for your self invented operators. If this thing goes "public" and has more than a few users, it is only a matter of time before someone shows up and wants AND to precede OR. And some way of having "parenthesises" to enable grouping of terms.

Comment: Not to mention someone in the future may want to use `AND`/`OR` as (part of) key or value, not operator which probably means need for adding escaping or quotes.